# Flutter 1px bug on Shadermask when TileMode.repeated

Tags: flutter, mask

I looking to avoid this scenario where it looks like
there is 1px in between tiles.

Am trying to have a background masked into multiples widgets.

```
ShaderMask(
    blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
    shaderCallback: (bounds) => ImageShader(
        snapshot.data!,
        TileMode.repeated,
        TileMode.repeated,
        Matrix4.identity().storage,
    ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Premaded the tiles before using the asset on flutter. sure it makes the picture bigger wich is not what i want. but it manages to not display any artifacts on the screen so far.

[image]